# ADF delete activity with python- Unable to create logging

Tags: python, azure-data-factory

I am currently creating adfv2 delete activity with python using below code

My python code looks like below

```
#Create a delete activity 

blob_ls_name = 'AzureBlobLS'
ds_name = 'Dataset_Test'
dataset_name = DatasetReference(reference_name= ds_name)
ds_ls = LinkedServiceReference(reference_name=blob_ls_name)
logsettings = LogStorageSettings(linked_service_name = ds_ls,  path = 'mycontainer/path')
act_name = 'CleanUp_Dest_Folder'
act_delete = DeleteActivity(name = act_name , dataset = dataset_name, log_storage_settings = logsettings)
```

Even after creating logsettings, when the delete activity is created the log settings are not properly applied in the activity and it is selecting nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, you missed the [`enable_logging = True`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.deleteactivity?view=azure-python#parameters) in the last line, add it like below, then it will work fine.

```
act_delete = DeleteActivity(name = act_name , dataset = dataset_name, enable_logging = True, log_storage_settings = logsettings )
```

---

**My test sample:**

It creates a pipeline with a delete activity.

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.datafactory.models import *

subscription_id = 'xxxxx'
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id='xxxx', secret='xxxx', tenant='xxx')
adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

blob_ls_name = 'AzureBlobStorage2'
ds_name = 'Binary1'
dataset_name = DatasetReference(reference_name= ds_name)
ds_ls = LinkedServiceReference(reference_name=blob_ls_name)
logsettings = LogStorageSettings(linked_service_name = ds_ls,  path = 'test/d2')
act_name = 'CleanUp_Dest_Folder'
act_delete = DeleteActivity(name = act_name , dataset = dataset_name, enable_logging = True, log_storage_settings = logsettings )

rg_name = 'xxxx'
df_name = 'joyfactory'
p_name = 'Pipeline1234'
params_for_pipeline = {}
p_obj = PipelineResource(
    activities=[act_delete], parameters=params_for_pipeline)
p = adf_client.pipelines.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, p_name, p_obj)
print(p.activities[0].log_storage_settings.linked_service_name)
```

[image]

Check in the portal:

[image]

Comment: thanks. this solved the issue, but I have another issue after the pipeline is created. After the pipeline is created, when I selected delete activity ( just select and no change performed) the publish is getting enabled saying there is a change to pipeline. Do you also have the similar issue?

Comment: @kishore Yes, I also meet this issue, not sure why, but once we click the publish button, it will never happen again.

Comment: Yes, I even observed the same behavior. After the first publish, it's not appearing again